# how to get this adapter to work with aircrack-ng?

Tags: aircrack-ng

I have a usb wifi adapter:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter
```

I start it in monitor mode like this:

`airmon-ng start wlan1`

And it says monitor mode was enabled [supposedly in wlan1]

So I do a test:

`aireplay-ng -9 wlan1`

But it says it found 0 APs.  I tried compat-wireless, downloaded it and then compiled.  And rmmoded the rt2800 modules, then tried to insert rt2800usb.ko, and it said something about unknown symbols, or something like that.

Comment: Are you sure the monitor mode is not enabled in mon0? try entering the command as `aireplay-ng -9 mon0`. The output of airmon-ng should indicate in what interface the monitor mode was enabled

Comment: I'm almost positive.  It said "monitor mode enabled on wlan0", **not** mon0.  It stuck out to me because I'd always have mon0 in the past [with my other zd1211rw usb wifi adapter]

Answer (score 1):

First try to install bt5 R1 which has all the wireless drivers patched and check then with (double check if you have any AP in your range):

```
aireplay-ng -9 wlan1
```

If it displays `0 AP`, then read from [rt2870](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=rt2870) and then on the forums.

*Note:* aircrack works for 100% on WEP but with WPA/WPA2 only with a dictionary which is a waste of time IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Goto official site, and check for your adapter. 
There may be some patches for it. 
Otherwise you won't be able to run it

http://aircrack-ng.org

http://patches.aricrack-ng.org